# JS: Getting "0" if input or formula result has decimal value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a virtual shop.

Everything works fine unless the input values are decimal despite they're being declared as decimals, as you can see in the attached printscreens.

How do I get past this?

```
var total = (parseInt($("#quantity").val()) * parseFloat($("#price").val())) +
                (parseInt($("#quantity").val()) * parseFloat($("#price").val() * (parseFloat($("#IVA").val()) / 100)));

            $("#total").val(total);
```

```
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal IVA { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj3ti.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnJ1E.png

Comment: Images are bad, copy and pasteable code is good.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with currency, you probably want to use toFixed() to round all your values to 2 decimal places.

```
var total = "246.6880000000000001" * 1;
console.log(total.toFixed(2)); // outputs 246.69
```

Not only is this good for trimming long trailing rounding errors, but it will also help with formating things like 147.6 to 147.60 so that it is all in the same standard currency format.

Comment: I'm aware of using toFixed(2), actually it is implemented, but my problem is that if I use a decimal input it records "0"

Comment: Just ran a test to try to recreate the problem and remembered that toFixed() does not like to cast strings the way JS normally does.  Input values are strings, so you need to make it a number first.